# Why the subject unsubscribed in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, polling

I'm trying to do a http polling by Rxjs (request, idle a certain time after get result, and then request again), but still got a few questions not very cleared, could someone can help to explain?

Q1: I emit a value to load$ from load$'s pipe line, is it a good way implement the polling strategy (it works in current mode, just no idea is it a best practice)

Q2: I understand when checkbox ticked the pauser$ will add a subscriber to load$, so the load$ loop fired, but when the checkbox untick, pauser just switch to an empty stream, it's fine, but why load$ stopped? no one unsubscribe it right? (although yes, currently it works as expected, but why?)

```js
        
        const load$ = new BehaviorSubject('').pipe(
            concatMap(_ => concat(
                from(makePromise()).pipe(tap(v => dispatchEvent(v)), tap(v => log("idle "))),
                of('').pipe(delay(2000)),
                // interval(1000).pipe(take(3), tap(v => log("idle " + v))),
                of('').pipe(tap(_ => load$.next('')), skip(1))
            ))
        );

        pauser$ = fromEvent(document.querySelector("#tick"), "click")
            .pipe(
                pluck("target", "checked"),
                switchMap(checked => checked ? load$ : empty())
            )
            .subscribe(_ => _!="" && console.log(_));
```

Answer (score 0):

After checked document https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html, it's cleared for Q2 now, the switchMap will automatic complete previous inner observable.